# How is OpenCV finding contours with 0 area and 0 length in pixels?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a folder full of images that are mostly black with some white spots sprikled in (PNGs, one is attached as an example). I wrote a code to output the area of each contour it finds, but the majority of contours it finds have 0 area. Since it's being mesured in pixels I'm very confused why it thinks these artifacts exist.

This is the code:

```
    black = (0,0,0)
    color0 = (0,0,255) #Blue Green Red

    directory = 'C:/Users/mtl/PIPELINE/SUBTRACTED_deNoised_completed_frames/*.PNG' 
    file_list = glob.glob(directory)

    # Read through folder and contour #
    i=0
    for filename in file_list:
        img_read = cv2.imread(filename)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img_read, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 5, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        contours, _= cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        black_image = np.zeros((1192, 1192, 3), dtype=np.uint8)  

        for cnt in contours :
            color=0
            area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
            print(area)
```

it outputs numbers, but most of the numbers are 0, why might it think a contour with no area exists? especially since (I think) the unit of mesurement is in pixels.

Comment: Contour of an isolated pixel consists of a single coordinate (a point). From the perspective of geometry point has no size, hence the area of that contour is 0. | Note that documentation says: "Similarly to moments , the area is computed using the Green formula. Thus, the returned area and the number of non-zero pixels, if you draw the contour using `drawContours` or` fillPoly` , can be different."

Comment: Same question as the duplicate, considering area is the 0th order moment. Existing answer exactly explains the problem. OpenCV is broken.